# Angular call function to capture div and wait for the cappture before continuing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method that captures a div. I call this method called capture() from another method.

Here's the code:

```
theimage; // define the variable


callcapture() {

  // do stuff

  this.capture(); // Call the method here 

  // Do other stuff below BUT (Do not run the rest of the code until "this.capture() has finished ")

}


capture() {
  const element = document.getElementById("capture") as HTMLCanvasElement;
  html2canvas(element).then((canvas) => {
    this.theimage = canvas.toDataURL();
  });
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Angular's `@viewChild` for that? It's rarerly a good idea to use native JS methods like `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName` etc; in an Angular application.

```
    <canvas #myCanvas></canvas>
```

```
    @ViewChild('myCanvas', {static: false}) canvasElem: ElementRef;
```

And then you work with that :

```
const context = this.canvasElem.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
const base64:string = this.canvasElem.nativeElement.toDataURL();
```

Comment: +1. Using `document.getElementById("capture")` in an Angular app would sweep the entire DOM instead of just the respective component template. It's better to use Angular native method `@ViewChild` here. Also you wouldn't need to fiddle with async in that case. In this case just don't forget to call the function inside the hook `ngAfterViewInit()` so that the `<canvas>` is already rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the promise and use another `then` to make sure the element has been *captured* already:

```
callcapture() {
  // do stuff
  this.capture().then(() => {
    // Do other stuff below BUT (Do not run the rest of the code until "this.capture() has finished ")
  });
}

capture() {
  const element = document.getElementById("capture") as HTMLCanvasElement;
  return html2canvas(element).then((canvas) => {
    this.theimage = canvas.toDataURL();
  });
}
```

Comment: IMO `async/await` would be cleaner to use here.